# Rails Facebook - unable to fetch additional user information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

my goal is to fetch user localisation.
I use:

```
gem 'koala'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

This is my devise.rb config

```
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FB_APP_ID'], ENV['FB_APP_SECRET'],
                  scope: ['email', 'user_location'],
                  callback_url: ENV['FB_CALLBACK_URL'],
                  info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name, name, location'
```

In my `OmniauthCallbacksController` controller in `facebook` method, I want to create a user and assign localisation to him.

```
  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
  @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(ENV['FB_APP_ID'], ENV['FB_APP_SECRET'], ENV['FB_CALLBACK_URL'])
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@user.omni_auth_settings.first.access_token)
```

Unfortunately facebook API still returns only the following data:

```
=> {"provider"=>"facebook",
 "uid"=>"1091157110258285",
 "info"=>
  {"email"=>"wfhllalscu_1552944302@tfbneew.net",
   "name"=>"Emma Alcdgiehdgbgb Fergiesen",
   "first_name"=>"Emma",
   "last_name"=>"Fergiesen",
   "image"=>"http://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/1091157110258285/picture"},
 "credentials"=>
  {"token"=>
    "EAAEobjagyisBAFKrkigZA4p09xvxVOKK41LbPEHKFASCGrz0f5ZCIgwwdjBq1UPf5jvkmdzjhnytZAKVwDb4MrrzWvkC0y1LLJ8RZCpKcA4tTHty3pGxjFvoKzqb5RLYUvSP1Y5GL0A09ZClM5FsEX464sVnmKXXi6Bg4F0qbAYikFFNFQifsQ",
   "expires_at"=>1558216434,
   "expires"=>true},
 "extra"=>
  {"raw_info"=>{"email"=>"wfhllalscu_1552944302@tfbnw.net", "first_name"=>"Emma", "last_name"=>"Fergiesen", "name"=>"Emma Alcdgiehdgbgb Fergiesen", "id"=>"1091157110258285"}}}
```

When I request directly `/me` still I do not receive birthday and localisation.

```
[6] pry(#<Users::OmniauthCallbacksController>)> @graph.get_object("me")
=> {"name"=>"Emma Alcdgiehdgbgb Fergiesen", "id"=>"1091157110258285"}
```

Privileges are granted for these users. I have no idea why I cannot fetch those data.
Any ideas?

Comment: You have to ask for the fields you want

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Specifying the info_fields should already do that. (If you made this /me request you mentioned at the end yourself, outside of omniauth, you need to specify them via the `fields` parameter.)